# IBMIOTF Can a device subscribe to an event?

Tags: android, ibm-cloud, mqtt, iot

I have looked around and read through the documentation, but I cannot find any mention of a device subscribing to an event from a different device?

My set up is that I have 2 devices, and 1 application. I would like one device to be able to receive events from the other, without having to use the application as a relay (in that the application receives the event, and re-emits it as a command).

The device to receive the event is Android, and although I believe I can subscribe to the correct topic I will not receive any data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A device can only subscribe to commands - it cannot subscribe to the event topics of other devices.

Only applications have the access needed to subscribe to events - so you would have to use the message relay approach.